# PHP set assigned variable to undefined - it stays the same?

Tags: php, undefined, undefined-behavior

I have question about some behavior I was just debugging, specifically what happens if a variable which is already set is assigned to an undefined value. I just want to check that I'm understanding what happened correctly. If a variable has a value set already, and you try to set it to something undefined, it stays at its old value?

Specifically, I had some PHP code that looked approximately like this - assume that $string is some string of 1's and 2's.

```
$array = array(1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar');
for($count=0;$count<len($string);$count++)
{
    $newvar = $array[$string[$count]];
    if(!empty($newvar))
    {
       switch($newvar)
       {
             case 'foo':
                    // blah blah break;
             case 'bar':
                    // blah blah break;
       }
    }
}
```

Now, my code was supposed to set $string to be something like "12212", but an error on my part was sending it something with extra spaces at the end - "12212   ". This caused some aberrant behavior, and I think what happened was this - when $count=5, $string[5] is undefined, so $array[$string[5]] is undefined, and $newvar stays as 2. Thus my if(!empty statement doesn't do its job and case 'bar' happens more times than it should have. Does that all seem like what would happen?

Of course, trimming $string solved my problem, but I want to make sure I understand what was going wrong. Apologies if this is a stupid question - I'm just an amateur here....

Edit: Here's the actual code. $upstr is supposed to be a string of digits.

```
           $len = strlen($upstr);
           $cost=0;
           $upnames = array(4=>"man", 2=>"raw", 1=>"food", 3=>"fuel",5=>"tech");
           for($strloop=0;$strloop<$len; $strloop++)
           {
                 $number = $upstr[$strloop];
                 if(! empty($number))
                 {
                     $name = $upnames[$number];
                     $cost+= mysql_result($result1,0,$name) +1;
                     if(mysql_result($result2,0,$name."up")==1)
                     {
                         $cost+=100;
                     }
                 }
           }
```

What happened when $upstr had some extra spaces at the end was I would see a mysql error, that it couldn't find the column "up" in $result2 . So it was trying to run that block of code in the if() statement with $name being empty or NULL or something. And if I intentionally added 3 or 4 extra spaces, I would see that many mysql errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the definition of variable $array is incorrect in your code example, it should read as follows:

$array = array(1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar');

If you set $newvar to an undefined element of $array (e.g. 3) then $newvar will be set to NULL.

Comment: Thanks - just corrected that in the original question. So if $newvar is NULL, then my if(!empty($newvar)) statement should have jumped me out of the switch? It didn't seem to be....

Comment: Yes, when $newvar is NULL, then empty($newvar) should evaluate to true, but IMHO the following solution would be cleaner: if (empty($newvar)) { break; }

Comment: Strange, because I was getting errors that told me the switch was actually happening... should I post the actual code I have?

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_key_exists($array, $string[$count])` to check if your array has value for your key.

Comment: Thanks - that's another good solution. But I'm more interested in why what I had was going wrong. I'd just like to understand any unexpected behavior I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out what was causing the behavior I saw. The strings '' and ' ' behave differently under empty(). One of them is considered empty and the other isn't, which was confusing me. Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: u should write this in comments, as this is not the answer

Comment: You can use trim($upstr) to remove unnecessary spaces from the beginning and the end of the string. It would also be a good ide to use an array of digits instead of a string to iterate through it. Another idea is to do something like this: $up_arr = str_split(trim($upstr)) as this will split up the characters of the trimmed string into an array.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Trimming is the solution I'm using. I was really just asking because I didn't know what was going wrong. So this is, in fact, the answer to my question, which was "why are extra spaces screwing up this code?", not "how do I get rid of extra spaces?"...whether it will be helpful to anyone else is debatable. The issue with using an array is that $upstr is getting passed from an html form, so AFAIK I can't send an array that way - just a string.